# had difficulty finding a place to stay

Tags: meaning, infinitives, present-participles

> a. I had a difficulty to find a place to stay.
>
> b. I had difficulty to find a place to stay.
>
> c. I had a difficulty finding a place to stay.
>
> d. I had difficulty finding a place to stay.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

Which are natural?

Do they mean the same?

I use (d) myself and think it is grammatical. I am not sure about the other ones.
To me, (c) means that while I was finding a place to stay I encountered a difficulty. That doesn't mean the same as (d).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

d) is indeed the form I would expect to hear.

"A difficulty" sounds unnatural. If you wanted to indicate there was one specific snag, then instead of "I had a difficulty" you would probably say instead "I had a problem".

"Difficulty to find" is definitely unnatural.